# Rosdep for svn repository, similar to libAria

Tags: ros, rosdep, svn, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

we would like to simplify the dependencies installation process using rosdep. It deals easily with debian packages but we would like to use source code from svn too.

In the [answer 74404](http://answers.ros.org/question/74404/rosdep-how-to-define-dependency-management-on-custom-package) says that "rosdep is not designed to pull packages from source" but we found [ROSAria's libaria.rdmanifest](https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria/blob/master/libaria.rdmanifest) and how they do that, even though it's a bit tricky, we have found a way to use svn. Anyway,

- Is there a way to add svn dependencies a bit more cleanly?
- We have found out that a tar.gz file is needed in "uri:", how can we get rid of it?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/139706/rosdep-for-svn-repository,-similar-to-libaria/) by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 843 on 2014-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The rdmanifest specification is described in [REP-112](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0112.html).

It doesn't look like there's support for checking out dependencies directly from SVN.

In general, depending on checking out and installing HEAD from an SVN repository is a bad idea, because it exposes your software to regressions and API changes in the package you're depending on. You should instead depend on a specific version of your dependency, and the easiest way to do this is by depending on a release tarball.

rdmanifest dependencies are also a bad idea because they will probably prevent your package from ever being released to debs.

You may also want to look into the process for packaging and releasing your dependency as a third-party library as described in [REP-136](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0136.html)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1